# Add javascript to django admin site

Tags: django, checkbox, django-admin, sum

I followed these steps:

1. settings.py

> ```
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
> MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
> ```

2. urls.py

> ... + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

3. save demo.js here myapp/static/myapp/js/demo.js

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     $("h1").css("background-color","red");
> });
> ```

4. admin.py

> ```
> class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     class Media:
>         js = ['myapp/js/demo.js']
> admin.site.register(MyModel, BaseAdmin)
> ```

when I open admin site, nothing changed. which step is wrong?
p.s. running development server "runserver"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a couple of things:

1. `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`
2. `(function ($) {
       $(document).ready(function ($) {
           $("h1").css("background-color","red");
       });
   })(django.jQuery);`